# List to datagridView datasource

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a class :

```
    class TermekRendeles
    {
        public int TermekID;
        public string TermekNev;
        public int Mennyiseg;
    }
```

And a list of it:

```
    List<TermekRendeles> TermekLista;
```

Which consists of data like:

```
     1 | X | 2  
     2 | Y | 3
```

And I want it as a datasource of a `DataGridView` (and it to show the data like above). I have been trying different ways, wanted it in a `ListBox` first, but figured the `DataGridView` would be easier, but still can't get it. Most recent try:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = TermekLista;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

But it just doesn't do anything, it stays a blank dgw. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Properties, not Fields:

```
class TermekRendeles
{
  public int TermekID {get; set;}
  public string TermekNev {get; set;}
  public int Mennyiseg {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, it works! I can't believe I couldn't find this out so long.